# TypeScript conditional type extends keyof but still cannot be used to index type

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

I wrote custom types in TypeScript using the template literal types to dynamically type the getters / setters of fields. The types look like this ([Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDiwY2FAzgHgBUA+OAXjgG8AoOOAbQGk4BLAOzgAMBzTAEkoBhAIZgWMYQBsWAL2D4A1sEQQAZnEJwAZHFwwo7bsQC+nALoAuOM1DY2AE1xdeMAe1U44AZVNwA-HAAFLR03nC2wA5OSirqmgGBAJTkpIT0XmZwVsGhoQCqbADGouJSsvJepBFRcDFqGv5ByWSp9AXFYhLScviVmVZswABuOCF0iSHJA8M4ANzUxvPUoJCwCMioXpjYeESkFDR0TKwcnLj8QiVd5YrK9Zo6egZsRqaW1uEgdo5c566U7k8Pk4jRyoS8n2+0TucVBgwA7gA1KQAV2AVjSGWapCGEBY9iyQTG+SKVzKPUqkMiPzqsISCORkjRGLapM65IqxDM2LguPxhMGIygxIm4wFMyg80W1CAA)):

```ts
export type Getters<T> = {
  [K in `get${Capitalize<keyof T & string>}`]: K extends `get${infer S}` ? (
    S extends keyof T ? () => T[S] : (
      Uncapitalize<S> extends keyof T ? () => T[Uncapitalize<S>] : never
    )
  ) : never;
};

export type Setters<T> = {
  [K in `set${Capitalize<keyof T & string>}`]: K extends `set${infer S}` ? (
    S extends keyof T ? (newValue: T[S]) => void : (
      Uncapitalize<S> extends keyof T ? (newValue: T[Uncapitalize<S>]) => void : never
//                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    )
  ) : never;
};
```

However, I face a type error line 12 (highlighted above), in the `Setters<T>` type definition, saying:

> Type 'Uncapitalize' cannot be used to index type 'T'.

I'm a bit confused because I checked that `Uncapitalize<S> extends keyof T` just before, and while *I might understand why there still is a type error* (I don't know but maybe generic types can be different and two calls to `Something<T>` in a row might return a different type?), what really surprise me is that it worked a few lines above, in the `Getters<T>` type definition... The main question that come to my mind now is: What is the difference between them? Why is one throwing a type error and not the other?

EDIT (I forgot to mention it the first time): I am aware that I can duplicate the type check inside the type of the parameter (as mentioned by @AntonKastritskiy in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75551321/21276039)), but I would like to avoid this repetition, and furthermore understand what happens here

---

By the way, maybe there is a better way to do this (especially to keep a reference to the current `keyof T` being iterated, rather than needing to "deconstruct" the generated getter/setter name), but I tried my best to do it alone, as a kind of "exercise", but now I'm open to other improvement suggestion, if any

Answer (score 2):

I do not know the exact answer to your question. The error only seem to reproduce when the type is used for a parameter but not the return type. You can remove the error by adding one more check to ensure that Uncapitalised is a keyof T in the parameters, ie

```js
export type Setters<T> = {
  [K in `set${Capitalize<keyof T & string>}`]: K extends `set${infer S}` ? (
    S extends keyof T ? (newValue: T[S]) => void : (
      Uncapitalize<S> extends keyof T ? (newValue: Uncapitalize<S> extends keyof T ? T[Uncapitalize<S>] : never) => void : never
    )
  ) : never;
};
```

PS: I want to point out that even though the code tries to handle a case when a field can start with an uppercase letter. This still won't handle a case when two cases differ by the casing of their first letter. For example:

```js
type Foo = Setter<{a: number, A: string}> // {setA: string}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yeah I kind of noticed it before (but I forgot to mention it, I'll update the question), however this feels like a lot of repetition and it was what I tried to avoid. But ultimately, I'll fallback to this...
PS: I am aware of the 1st letter case issue, but I have no idea how I can handle it better? I mean, what would you do if you needed to write explicit setters? `seta(...)` and `setA(...)`?

Comment: Personally I prefer the `obj.set(prop, value)` format. This way we get to avoid this question completely. and if the state of `obj` is typed you also get autocompletion for `prop` in typescript.

Comment: Hmm year I see, that's a cleaver solution to avoid the problem! However, in my use case, the final object must contains all the `set*(...)` methods, but I came up with a way to generate `seta(string)` and `setA(number)` so I'm fine with that now :) I'm still looking for a way to avoid some of these repeating type-checks now